# Trigger PHP function with HTML button

Tags: php, html, function

I have a simple function that deletes a row from a database...

```
<?php
function messaging_remove_message($tmp_mid) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "messages WHERE message_ID = %d", $tmp_mid ));
}
?>
```

What I am trying to do now is have this trigger when a delete button is pressed.  I know that you can't trigger PHP functions with HTML so what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of the options would be to use AJAX. Use the following example:

**page.php**

```
<?php
// ...... include necessary config etc files
messaging_remove_message($_GET['mid']);
function messaging_remove_message($tmp_mid) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "messages WHERE message_ID = %d", $tmp_mid ));
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<button onclick="call_remove_msg(<?php echo $msg_id; ?>)">Delete</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_remove_msg(id){
    $.get("page.php?mid=" + id, function(){alert("Comment deleted!");});
}
</script>
```

This is technically be improved with AJAX. Learn more for your development here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the $_POST array to check if the button is clicked:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['buttonname'])) {
       messaging_remove_message($var);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Cannot call this from html as the question says.

Comment: You need to add the code to construct the form to make this a complete answer.

Comment: Ah, haven't read the first line. Then use $_GET instead of $_POST. if(isset($_GET['mid'])) ....